# использование Websocket на сайте

Tags: php, websocket

У меня на сайте надо будет использовать следующие возможности

1. В случае личных сообщений что бы появлялась информация (примерно как
   я facebook)
2. Общий чат.
3. При изменении цены на товар продавцем
   изменение цены.
4. Личный чат

Как это реализовать? Использовать json и if? Или путем использования нескольких websocket. Если есть примеры на решения ссылки только приветствуются.

Comment: аякс помойму более подойдет

Comment: http://reactphp.org/, http://socketo.me/. GOOGLE ?

Comment: Пожалуйста, старайтесь выражать свои мысли яснее и четче. Начинайте предложения с заглавной буквы, используйте знаки препинания. Сейчас ваш вопрос довольно сложно читать и понимать и это уменьшает шансы получить хороший ответ.

Comment: @NickVolynkin поправил

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чат можно реализовать на node.js  мануалов очень много, обменивайтесь сообщениями в json. в json можно завести поле type_msg если значение public то сообщение в общий чат, если private то сообщение личное, в этом случае передаем id - которому будем отсылать сообщение, а при реализации массива активных пользователей вставлять индексом id пользователя.
Изменение цены можно выводить всплывающим сообщением.

Comment: То есть json и if

Comment: Да, не обязательно if можно  switch))

Comment: я не про исполнение я о принципе. А вместе нельзя запустить ?

Comment: можно, все зависит от реализации

Comment: вопрос в следующем можно ли запустить несколько websocet сереверов на одном сайте

Comment: Можно, но зачем? Сервер один который будет с ними работать, работайте с одним соединением, сделайте просто типизацию сообщений, и обрабатывайте по-разному

Comment: не правильно прочитал вопрос, да можно запускать несколько серверов,но опять же вопрос зачем?

Comment: ну вот https://github.com/morozovsk/websocket-examples/tree/master/chat2 а точнее здесь https://github.com/morozovsk/websocket-examples/tree/master/chat2/server , здесь я так понимаю надо запускать два скрипта master и worker, а как это с консоли пока ума не приложу. Учитывая что они обращаются к одному серверу.

Comment: объясните зачем вам два сокет-сервера,если можно сделать все через один, и это будет лучшим решением?

Comment: F как это можно сделать запустив два скрипта master и worker